# Render Order of BufferGeometry in Thee.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

Following the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406302/transparency-of-shadermaterial-in-three-js), I'm dealing with building models in BufferGeometry, and realize that the `transparent` flag affects the render order: objects with transparent materials will be rendered after non-transparent ones.

Also, I read from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657444/z-buffer-issue-with-buffergeometry-in-particlesystem), did an experiment on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccyang/gteba6Ly/) and realized the render order of faces in BufferGeometry is the same as the order they are specified in buffers, but not distance from cameras. (In the above experiment, I specify a closer triangle first in the buffer, and it occludes others behind it.)

So my question is: is it possible to set render order of faces manually in BufferGeometry?
In my case, I  may need to change transparency of building elements dynamically.
(I've read the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs/15995475#15995475) saying we can set `renderOrder` of Object3D.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faces are rendered in the order in which they appear in the `BufferGeometry`.

If you have to vary the transparency of scene elements dynamically, I suggest you maintain separate geometries, each paired with its own material.

The renderer will render the objects having `transparent = false` first. Then it will render the objects having `transparent = true`.

You will likely find you have fewer artifacts if you use the following settings for your transparent materials:

```
material.transparent = true;
material.opacity = 0.5; // or as desired
material.depthTest = true; // the default
material.depthWrite = false; // use for transparent materials only
```

Also, self-transparency is particularly tricky. An example would be a semi-transparent cube (or building). One way to reduce artifacts in such situations is to render the object twice: first with `material.side = THREE.BackSide` and then again with `material.side = THREE.FrontSide`. You can use `object.renderOrder` to force a specific render order between objects.

three.js r.75